# Discrete Math Combinatorics dice

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, dice

I just can't figure this one out:

Throw 5 times a dice with 6 sides colored in: blue, red, yellow, green, orange (5 colors)

1. How many possibles answers for getting at least one cube with '3'?
2. Exactly one cube with '2', and exactly one with with '4'?

I don't understand what the colors has to do with the numbers of the dice. I would be very grateful if someone explained what is the difference

Comment: As far as I can tell, the colors mean nothing for the question asked

Comment: You are throwing five dice each with a distinct colour and six-sides. The colours are mentioned to clarify that the dice are distinguishable, and thus that order matters when counting *distinct* outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand what the colors has to do with the numbers of the dice.

You are throwing five dice each with a distinct colour and six-sides.   The colours are mentioned to *clarify* that the dice are *distinguishable*, and thus that *order matters* when counting *distinct* outcomes.   That is all.

> 1 How many possible answers for getting at least one cube with '3'?

Hint: Use Complements.

> 2 Exactly one cube with '2', and exactly one with with '4'?

Hint: Count ways to select colours for each of these numbers, and multiply ways the remaining colours can have non-2-or-4 results.